# Passar valor de input para variável PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Estou usando o JavaScript para setar um `input` tipo `hidden` em uma janela modal. Agora, preciso atribuir o valor que foi preenchido nesse campo a uma variável PHP. Não estou usando nenhum formulário, apenas o campo isoladamente. Tentei o seguinte código que não funciona:

```
    <?php
        $x = "<script>document.write(bookId)</script>";
        echo $x;
    ?>
```

Como faço para pegar o valor deste campo e atribuir para a variável?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Provavelmente você precisa enviar uma requisição para acessar essa variável através de `$_POST` ou `$_GET`

Comment: Algo como: `$x = "<script>document.write($bookId);</script>"`, em que `$bookId` tem o valor de `$_POST['bookId']` já verificado.

Comment: O `input` não está dentro de nenhum formulário? Você envia o valor do campo para o servidor via AJAX?

Comment: O input não está em nenhum formulário e seu valor não é enviado ao servidor , só utilizo ele porque preciso de alguma forma guardar um valor que foi enviado via javascript para a janela modal. Queria saber se há um modo de recuperar o valor desse campo e o atribuir a uma variável PHP sem acessá-lo por POST ou GET.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, vamos lá!

Quando você irá acessar tal valor em seu arquivo PHP? Se você não for acessar tal valor no PHP basta armazena-lo em uma variável Javascript (uma global).

Para definir uma variável global basta declara-la fora de alguma função ou (1), caso a declaração seja em uma função deve-se não usar o `var` (2). Ex:

1:

```
var valor = 10;

function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}
```

2:

```
function foo() {
    valor = 10;
    return 'bar';
}
```

Caso você realmente necessite acessar tal valor em seu arquivo PHP, basta definir o `value` do input com o valor do PHP e adicionar um `id` para identificar o campo (caso vá fazer uma requisição Ajax) ou adicionar o `name` para receber tal valor em seu arquivo PHP.

Ex:

```
<input type="hidden" id="meuValor" name="nameValor" value="<?php echo $valor; ?>" />
```

E, após já possuir tal valor em seu HTML basta chamar funções em eventos, por exemplo, onClick de algum botão, onKeyPress de algum input, etc.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Comment: Fabrício, acho que não fui claro, deixa eu explicar melhor. Tenho uma tabela em uma página, sendo que em cada linha dela há um ícone que quando clicado abre uma janela modal. Dentro dessa janela modal serão exibidas outras informações sobre esse registro. Usando JavaScript eu mando para a janela modal a chave primária referente ao registro clicado. Eu precisava atribuir o valor dessa chave à uma variável PHP declarada dentro da janela modal, para depois realizar uma pesquisa exibir outros dados. Como não consigo atribuir esse valor diretamente à variável PHP ...

Comment: eu estou definindo esse valor para um input, para depois, tentar pegar esse valor e atribuir à variável PHP. Uma gambiarra doida! Resumindo: Preciso que uma variável PHP dentro da minha modal receba um valor passado pelo JavaScript.

Comment: Oi João Paulo, o modal é aberto após a resposta de uma requisição Ajax? Se sim, aproveite essa requisição para enviar o valor ao PHP e adiciona-lo ao modal. Uma opção seria também persistir tal valor em uma chave da sessão ($_SESSION['seuvalor']), sempre que o modal for reaberto você reescreve esse valor, e, para usa-lo no PHP você apenas recupera o mesmo.